# Higher direct image for rational singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, singularity-theory

Let $X$ be a normal, projective (complex) variety with at worst rational singularities. Let $\pi:Y \to X$ be the resolution of singularities obtained by blowing-up the singular points. Is $R^1 \pi_*\mathbb{Z}=0$? I am mainly interested in the case when $X$ is of dimension $3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be true. Use the exponential sequence to obtain
$$\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y\to \pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y^*\to R^1\pi_*\mathbb{Z}\to R^1\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y$$
The last term is zero since you have rational singularities. You can check that the first map is surjective as follows: By normality
$$\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y = \mathcal{O}_X,\quad \pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y^* = \mathcal{O}_X^*$$
Choose a local embedding $X\subset Z$, with $Z$ smooth. Consider the diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
 \mathcal{O}_Z & \xrightarrow{exp}&\mathcal{O}_Z^* \\ 
\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
 \mathcal{O}_X & \xrightarrow{exp}&\mathcal{O}_X^*
\end{array}
$$
The top  arrow $exp$ is surjective, and the vertical arrows are surjective. Therefore the bottom $\exp$ is surjective.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not quite see the surjectivity of the first map.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand.